# shlex.split failed on "kill -9 $(pgrep Electron)"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to close vscode with command:

```
In [8]: cmd = "kill -9 $(pgrep Electron)"
In [11]: subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
Out[11]: <subprocess.Popen at 0x10d1d0438>
```

It worked, but when I tried an alternative without shell=True

```
In [13]: cmd = "kill -9 $(pgrep Electron)"
In [14]: cmd = shlex.split(cmd)

In [15]: cmd
Out[15]: ['kill', '-9', '$(pgrep', 'Electron)']

In [16]: subprocess.Open(cmd)
AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'Open'
```

How could I enable working as intended?

Comment: `$(` syntax is shell syntax so it requires `shell=True`.

Comment: The immediate error you see is not that, though, but is due to having written `subprocess.Open(...)` rather than `subprocess.Popen(...)` - missing the initial _P_ in the method name. As stated, it still not work, if you fix thatm unfortunately.